# MS Access ODBC problems

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, odbc

I have the following problems with using ODBC driver with MS Access database
my connection string for database is

```
private const string connectionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=D:\work\client.mdb;Pwd=sql;";
```

But when i try to connect to database i get error

```
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file 'D:\work\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug\dba.mdb'.
```

Ok, i've put mdb file to location D:\work\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug and rename it to dba.mdb
and get another error:

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid password.
```

Can anybody help me to solve problem.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a problem. It was because query to database included scheme name

```
SELECT CODE, ISOCODE FROM dba.Table1
```

It happens because my code must support two kind of databases MS SQL Server and MS Access. For MS SQL Server select works ok, but for Access it born not untestable errors, such i've posted  in my question above. When i've remove 'dba' from select it become working without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the UID:

Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=C:\mydatabase.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;

Comment: you can take a look at this helpful link: http://www.connectionstrings.com/access#p88